# Domain prefix expression in odoo

Tags: python, xml, odoo, odoo-8

i am trying to modify a domain but i have first to understand the logic of this prefix expression :

```
 <field name="partner_id" position="attributes">
                <attribute name="domain">[('state', '=', 'validate'),
                                            '|', '|',
                                                '&amp;',
                                                    ('supplier', '=', to_supplier), ('customer', '=', to_customer),
                                                '&amp;',
                                                    ('supplier', '=', True), ('customer', '=', True),
                                                ('is_project', '=', True)]
                </attribute>
```

i tried to convert it into infix expression (for my own understanding) so i got this :

```
('state', '=', 'validate'),[[('supplier', '=', to_supplier),'&amp;' ('customer', '=', to_customer)],'|',[('supplier', '=', True),'&amp;', ('customer', '=', True)], '|',
                                                ('is_project', '=', True)]
```

in a more simple way :
prefix : A,|,|,&,B,C,&,D,E,F
infix : A,(B&C | D&E| F)

i don't know if this is right or no

Comment: The following link explain working with domain and polish notations in Odoo https://www.surekhatech.com/blog/working-with-domain-and-polish-notations-in-od-1

Comment: @WaleedMohsen thank you, i understand how to go from infix to polish notation , but i have some troubles going from prefix to infix like the example that i gave.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, this is right:

```
[ A,
    '|', 
        '|',
            '&', B, C,
            '&', D, E,
        F]
```

is the same than

```
[
    '&'
    A,
    [
        '|', 
        [
            '|', 
            ['&', B, C,], 
            ['&', D, E,]
        ],
        F
    ]
]
```

To infix, it's this:

```
[
    A,
    '&',
    [
        [
            [B, '&', C,], 
            '|', 
            [D, '&',E,]
        ]
        '|', 
        F
    ]
]
```

which can be "simplified" to:

```
A, '&', [B, '&', C, '|', D, '&', E, '|', F]
```

in addition: In Odoo, if you don't write any operator, there is an implicit '&'